# Primary Key effects on multi user performance

Tags: sql-server

What will happen if i don't define any primary key in sql database and multiple users try to access same row at same time? Will it cause any performance issue or system crash? Duplication issue is taken care in code.

Comment: There is always a PK define the table.

Comment: Why would you not want a primary key?

Comment: A table without a clustered index (the primary key by default) is known as a heap and they are horrible from a performance perspective. And trust me, enforcing data integrity in your application is a very bad idea.

Comment: To answer your question it would be the same thing if there is a primary key. The system will take out a lock on the row for the first user and any subsequent attempts to read/write that row will be blocked until the lock is released.

Comment: A table w/o a clustered index works just like a table with a clustered index when all rows are selected. So sometimes it may be beneficial to have a table w/o a clustered index. For example, as staging table which is populated, and then all records moved elsewhere after some trivial transformations or checks which employ no `where` clauses and do not join to other tables, then the table is truncated/deleted.

Answer (score 0):

With the default configuration, a read will take a shared lock.  A shared lock does not block any other reads, but will block update/delete locks.
The existence of a primary key doesn't matter at this level as the row has already been identified.  Primary keys just enforce uniqueness using an index.

If a user attempts to change or delete a row, an exclusive lock is taken, which will block any other exclusive or shared locks.

The various isolation levels can change this behavior.